# Orchard Localization and query with Current culture filter does not return item with no translation

Tags: localization, orchardcms

I'm using Orchard CMS and I use localization part for my content types.

I also use ForCurrentCulture filter in queries to prepare cultured specific items for projection widgets and it works fine.

But the problem is that when I create a new item from a content type like news, after publishing it; the query doesn't return it until I click New Translation and save for one another language.

This bug occurs because the first created item does not belong to any language but this is not good. I think there should be a default culture for localization added content types.

Comment: Thank you Bertrand.  I copied this issue in issues part. If you mean I should take pics of my problem please tell me.

Comment: What is the url of the issue you created?

Comment: The url of issue is http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/21170

Comment: This is the url of solution: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/578763